# Create a Calculated Column in SQLAlchemy Core Table

Tags: python, database, orm, sqlalchemy

I have a SQLAlchemy table defined as following:

```
user = Table('user', MetaData(),
             Column('id', Integer),
             Column('first_name', String),
             Column('last_name', String))
```

I often need to refer the full_name of a user during query, for example:

```
sql = (select([
          user.c.id,
          (user.c.first_name + user.c.last_name).label('full_name')
       ]).where(user.c.id == 123))
```

Since full_name is used in many places, so such kind of code has a lot copies.

I wonder whether there is a way in SQLAlchemy I can create a calculated Column, so that I can conveniently use it just like other normal Column, the SQLAlchemy automatically converts it into `(user.c.first_name + user.c.last_name).label('full_name')` whenever I refer `user.c.full_name`

```
sql = (select([
          user.c.id,
          user.c.full_name
       ]).where(user.c.id == 123))
```

I searched and found there some solution in SQLAlchemy ORM using column_property or hybrid_property. The difference in my case is that I can only use **SQLAlchemy Core**.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to create calculated columns in sqlalchemy core. You don't need to do this however, all that is required is to save your expression in a variable and then use this in your select statements. If you have many of these to store then you could namespace them by storing them all in a collection. In the example below I've used an SQLAlchemy Properties object for this purpose so it will behave in similar manner to the columns collection.

```
class Table(sqlalchemy.Table):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.d = sqlalchemy.util._collections.Properties({})

user = Table('user', MetaData(),
             Column('id', Integer),
             Column('first_name', String),
             Column('last_name', String))
user.d.full_name = (user.c.first_name + user.c.last_name).label('full_name')
user.d.backwards_name = (user.c.last_name + user.c.first_name).label('backwards_name')

sql = (select([
          user.c.id,
          user.d.full_name
       ]).where(user.c.id == 123))
```

Comment: There may be name conflict if I create the derived column directly on table instance, `full_name` is just an example, actually it can be any words. My project heavily relies on the `table.c` to do a lot of column related check, so follow your suggestion, I can move the `full_name` to table.c, the `ColumnCollection` instance. But I checked the source code, ColumnCollection only accepts Column instance. If there is a way I can bypass and inject it to ColumnCollection, that is acceptable to me.

Comment: I've edited my answer to namespace the sql expressions by storing them in a new collection. It would be straightforward to monkeypatch the columns collection to accept these but this would likely break every other piece of code that expected to find only columns there. I would suggest that it makes sense to keep these collections separate as they contain different things. If you really wanted to access them together you could change `self.d = Properties({})` to `self.d = Properties(ChainMap({}, self.c._data))`. and access everything through `user.d` instead.

Comment: Thanks @EAW, though your idea doesn't solve all my concerns, this is still a very good direction for me. All original `Table` functionality will not be broken if using an extend property `d`